# Can not get key value from Redis in Express js

Tags: node.js, express, redis, jwt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a node express application running on localhost:3500 on windows 10 . I am using redis for storing refresh tokens . Redis server is running on localhost:6379 in Windows subsystem for linux (WSL2) .

But when i am setting key value pair from express it sets the value on redis but when i am trying to access it with key , it is not showing the value . Why it is happening ?

Redis Client:

```
const redis = require('redis');

const client = redis.createClient({
    port:"6379",
    host:"127.0.0.1"
});

client.connect().then(() => {
    console.log("Redis connected !!");
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
    const errr = new Error("Internal server error");
    errr.status = 500;
    next(errr);
});

client.on('connect',() => {
    console.log("Client connected to redis !!");
});

module.exports = client;
```

app.js file :

```
// Importing dependencies
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRouter = require('./routes/authRoutes');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
require('dotenv').config();
const client = require('./Helpers/redisConn');
const app = express();

client.set('foos','bars');
client.get('foos',(err,val) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    console.log(val);
});
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Even if redis is fast, setting keys is still an asynchronous process. I think you should ```await client.set('foos','bars');```. It is possible that the key is not defined before you try to acces it

Comment: Are you using node-redis v4? becuase if so you'll need to to use the returned promise instead of passing a callback